# How to pass JSON array of objects values to stacked chart using chart.js in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, bar-chart

I am implemeting stacked chart using chart.js
Here I am facing few challanges

1. Not able to pass currency values in currency format(means chart height is not visible I i pass amounts)
2. **How to pass json values to the chart**(In tootip I need to show **Total Limit(available+ulilized), Available Limit, Utilised Limit**

As per current implentaion I am passing available limit, utilized limit to the charts, how to pass total limit as well

3, How to handle click event,,( here I need comple object )

[image]

Please find this link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chart-js-tyggan?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchart.component.ts

If I pass amounts here chart not visible

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chart-js-phjtmz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchart.component.ts

Any one can suggest me

I solved tooptip issue but small thing still need to fix,
In tooltip no need to show color for total lmit

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chart-js-kreazz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchart.component.ts

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you are not passing the value of *totalLimit* in app.component.ts

So, I tried to fork your code and this is how the code is going to look like [Working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chart-js-zwpdup?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

I feel you can optimize your code in the way you are manipulating array values in app-component.

Comment: No, as per requirment  i need to show two colors bor but in tooltip allamount also need to show..is it possible ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chart-js-sadaqr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchart.component.ts just change the color of total limit to white or to the background of the page. Also, your question didn't have the requirement which you are mentioning.

Comment: But If I mention another label in tooltip its shows white color checkbox

Comment: I just couldn't understand why would you downvote this answer? The checkbox shows up as that is what chart.js expects and how it works. Help me with understanding the downvote.

Comment: And I am not quite sure how much of chart.js you have explored, you can customize the tooltip https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#external-custom-tooltips